# Git ошибка прав доступа

Tags: git, github

> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ **git remote add origin
>   https://github.com/pepelxD/works-cloud.git**
>
> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ **git remote -v origin**
>   https://github.com/pepelxD/works-cloud.git (fetch) origin
>   https://github.com/pepelxD/works-cloud.git (push)
>
> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ git **push -u github**
>   master fatal: 'github' does not appear to be a git repository fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Далее делаю так:

> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ **git push origin master**
>   Counting objects: 15, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (15/15), 3.29 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0
>   (delta 0) To https://github.com/pepelxD/works-cloud.git
>   7403f85..8d96036  master -> master
>
> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ **git push**
>    fatal: The  current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the current
>   branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin master
> ```
>
> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ  **git push --set-upstream origin master**
>     Branch master set up to track remote branch master from
>   origin. Everything up-to-date
>
> F:\OpenServer\domains\workbook.loc (master) λ **git push** 
>   Everything up-to-date

Может кто то объяснить что это такое было то?

Comment: Может надо `git push -u origin`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб та же беда

Comment: А что такое **github** у вас в командной строке?

Comment: @0andriy ,  Следующей командой вы занесете все изменения, которые были сделаны в локальном репозитории на Github.

git push -u github master

Ключ -u используется для того, чтобы установить связь между удаленным репозиторием github и вашей веткой master. Все дальнейшие изменения вы можете переносить на удаленный репозиторий упрощенной командой.

Comment: Ну вы делаете `git remote add origin`, когда подразумевается `git remote add github`. `Поэтому git push -u github` не проходит.